# WordPress - How to assign Page Templates to the Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

When creating standard pages we can use single or archive page templates or simply create our own page template creating a new page with the slug for example: `photography` and actual page: `page-photography.php` so we can write unique content to each page if we need to.

How can we do the same with custom post types?
So, I have a custom post type called `services` how can I create custom unique pages for each of my services?

I know I can write the content directly to each service page and pull it from there but this is not what I want. I would like to have full control over each service page.
Can anyone share the proper solution how to handle this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can create a file with name `single-{post-type}-{slug}.php`

see more here, [Single Post Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post)

Comment: Thank you @Asiqur, you are a genius! Creating pages like this `single-{post-type}-{slug}.php` works like a charm! May I ask if this is the only way and correct way to achieve this?

Comment: It is the default way WordPress provides. You can use hooks to achieve the same kind of results.